# Android: ручная смена языка интерфейса на нестандартный

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как лучше реализовать смену языка в при разработке приложений под Android, если это какие-нибудь нестандартные языки (например, диалекты китайского или устаревший русский)? Такие языки в принципе не логично настраивать автоматически, потому меня в этом вопросе интересуют две вещи:

- Как правильно в данном случае (т. е. ручная смена языка без локали) создать `res-файл` с дополнительным языком? Наверняка не так же, как [обычно](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/locale.php).
- Как лучше активировать этот язык через приложение? Понятно, что надо будет создать соответствующий пункт в настройках, но каком принципе следует создать метод, сменяющий язык интерфейса?

Comment: Можно изменить локаль по умолчанию.
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
Это точно работает для фарси, который как-то очень условно поддерживается андроидом и не может быть выбран в качестве языка системы. И для него можно создавать ресурсы с квантификатором fa. Но я не уверен что можно создавать ресурсы с совсем уж рандомным квантификатором и что это сработает для устаревшего русского.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создавать свои **собственные** локали. И работать с ними как со стандартными, как в плане ресурсов так и кода.

Например создадим локаль "ru_MY".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример переключения локалей есть на кртинке. но лучше приведу его кодом

```
// set your locale
    try {
        Constructor<Locale> constructor = Locale.class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Locale locale = constructor.newInstance("ru", "MY");  // <-- you locale (for example ru_MY)
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**PS** не забуде что диалект и страна разграничиваются буквой "r" **values-ru-rMY**

Comment: Благодраю Вас за ответ! Его очень долго не было.